# IRasterLayerExport3 doesn't save raster until ArcMap closes

Tags: raster, arcmap, arcobjects, vb.net

I'm trying to export raster using IRasterLayerExport3, but it saves raster file only after closing ArcMap. It seams that IRasterLayerExport3 creates placeholders for raster (empty file - 3kb), and it keeps all information in memory or maybe in temporary file. And it writes data to an empty file only after creating a new map document or closing ArcMap. Any ideas about this?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.  Be sure to include your cleanup code, because this is the likely cause.